# Add alt tag jQuery

Tags: jquery, alt

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#home').backstretch([
   "images/1.jpg", 
   "images/2.jpg", 
    ],  {duration: 2000, fade: 750});
});
```

});

I want to add alt tag. It is a piece of code related to home background slideshow.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What are you using for `backstretch`?

Comment: HI. Images for the slideshow background.

Comment: More specifically, what *plugin* are you using, not what data are you providing.

Comment: Solved with all info from @Eduardo. Thank you for trying to help me Freedomn-m.

Answer (score 1):

Each image in the set can be an object with options instead of a simple string with the image path. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch#image-definition) (i.e. the complete list of options).

```
$(function(){
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').backstretch([
     { url: "images/1.jpg", alt: "Some alt text" }, 
     { url: "images/2.jpg", alt: "Some alt text 2" },
    ],  {duration: 2000, fade: 750});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Eduardo. I used your code and now I have alt tags, but my images are not shown.

Comment: Try checking if the image urls are correct. You can inspect the background opening the images on new tabs.

Comment: Yes, this I checked twice (the path). And I used urls in both forms (images/1.jpg and www.example.com/images/1.jpg in the code), but still doesn`t work. Also, I inspected with Chrome / Developers tools / Elements and I see <img src="[object Object]" .

Comment: Now it works! I updated the specific min.js file from the link you shared and everything is OK. Thank you for help, @Eduardo!